# Concurrent Desktop Sessions Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

If a user is working on multiple projects (perhaps spanning multiple clients) concurrently, often it is useful to separate out workspaces.

e.g. for **client 1** you may have Visual Studio and Chrome (with client-specific cached credentials) open and for **client 2** you may have Microsoft Word and Chrome (with a *separate* set of client-specific cached credentials) open.

The requirement isn't necessarily to have concurrent rdp sessions (I think the only way to achieve this is a Windows hack), but rather to have Alt + Tab functionality that can switch between entirely new sets of open Windows applications.

Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows 10 has the ability to create multiple desktops, similar to how many desktops in Linux work.

[image: Image of Desktop Icon]

This Icon will show the standard Alt-Tab window, and provides the functions to add and remove desktops. (Look for the 'New desktop' icon in the right corner.)

I'm not sure how you'd manage to get a different set of credentials working in Chrome. Perhaps multiple chrome users will be able to handle this.

Comment: For the different credentials, using Incognito Mode works for me (until I switch Windows logins, or switch wi-fi networks, or reboot -- then I have to log everything in again).

Comment: True, but this can be rathertime consuming and irritating to use.